# abnormal angularjs behaviour in validation forms forbid to pick a date that should be accepted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, date

I want to make a validation of a date input using angularjs and I encounter a behaviour that seems wanted but I don't really understand its goal.

when you pick a date that is not valid (because it does not exist, or because it is out of the desired range) then the field behind ng-model is destroyed.

This is a flickr to show the problem : [link to plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qZbwUz6G1BLqpMYOPChC?p=preview)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Example - example-date-input-directive-production</title>   
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-rc.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="dateInputExample">

    <script>
      angular.module('dateInputExample', []).controller('DateController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.add=function(){
          $scope.example = {value: new Date(2016, 0, 15)};
        }
        $scope.add();
      }]);
    </script>

    <form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
      <label for="exampleInput">pick a date out of range (2016-01-15 : 2016-02-10) or that does not exist :</label>
      <input ng-show="example.value" type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd" min="2016-01-15" max="2016-02-10" required />
      <div role="alert">
        <button ng-show="!example.value" ng-click="add()">add the date</button>
      </div>
      <tt>value = {{example.value ? example.value  : "example.value has been destroyed"}}</tt><br/>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

My question is the following :

Is this behaviour normal or is it a bug ?

If this is the normal behaviour, how, in the previous example, may I pick the 2016-02-05 that should be a date inside the accepted range.

In this example, with this behaviour, I cannot pick a date in february.

Comment: it is a normal behaviour

Comment: I saw that this is the correct behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Actually for me it does look like a bug, at lest for the date validator. Maybe it can be expected in other situations, but this is what we have here:

1) Normal behavior - if we remove min/max validations and try to set incorrect date - it resets to the correct date, value does not disappear.

2) Add min/max validators, try to set date out of range - it resets to null.
Expected: it resets to previous correct value (as it does in "Normal behavior" case)

The workaround is to create a custom directive to keep the date value in the given range.
The essence of the directive is a $watch which checks if date is in range and fixes it if necessary:

```
scope.$watch(attr.ngModel, function(newValue) {
  if (minVal) {
    valid = !isValidDate(newValue) || angular.isUndefined(minVal) || parseDate(newValue) >= minVal;
    if (!valid) {
      // If date is less than min - set it to min
      // scope.example.value = minVal;
      ctrl.$setViewValue(attr.minDate);
      ctrl.$render();
    }
  }
  if (maxVal) {
    valid = !isValidDate(newValue) || angular.isUndefined(maxVal) || parseDate(newValue) <= maxVal;
    if (!valid) {
      // If date is greater than max - set it to max
      // scope.example.value = maxVal;
      ctrl.$setViewValue(attr.maxDate);
      ctrl.$render();
    }
  }
});
```

Here is a [plunker with demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BBr668?p=preview).